# Stop scrolling top by the click function of anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

I have an anchor tag which when clicked seems to scroll to the top of the screen.

I am using onclick and sending a model property to the function.

How can i prevent scrolling to top.

I have tried entering the **href as javascript:void(0);** and tried **returning false**.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="GetUsers('@(user.Code)');"><img ... /></a>

function GetUsers(Code) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });                                             
}
```

**Update**

Tried debugging it and it doesn't get to this line.

```
 var user = $(this).data('user-code');
```

Also no errors on page.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Admin/GetUsers/",
            data: { "User": user},
            success: function (data, textStatus) { ...
```

Doesn't get to this point...

**Update**

Now getting all the information, although the scrolling is still an issue. The prevent default doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: The `@(user.Code)`, is that some kind of template?

Comment: @parchment from the syntax I would guess Razor.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh, I'm not familliar with that... was going to point out you need to pass it somehow in your answer, but you already did that.

Comment: @parchment yep, just noticed myself :) thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes I'm using razor. @foreach (var user in Model)
                    {

Comment: Tried debugging it and it doesn't get to this line. var user = $(this).data('user-code'); Also no errors on page.

Comment: Did you try omitting the `href` attribute? In HTML5 this is valid (IIRC).

Comment: I just tried omitting the href with no prevail.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to stop the default action of the button. Firstly, use jQuery to attach your events instead of the outdated `on` attributes:

```
<a href="#" class="myLink" data-user-code="@(user.Code)"><img /></a>
```

Then in your jQuery event handler, you can use `preventDefault` on the passed event:

```
$('.myLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var user = $(this).data('user-code');
    $.ajax({
        // ajax settings...
    }); 
});
```

I used a `data` attribute on the element to hold the parameter which I'm guessing is required in your AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

A way to stop the scrolling without adding to javascript would be to set the href to an anchor with an ID that is not on the page, for example -

```
<a href="#!" onclick="GetUsers('@(user.Code)');"><img ... /></a>
```

Would work as it is unlikely that you will have an element with the name '!' on your page.